# Comparar textos php

Tags: php, comparação

Estou precisando desenvolver/utilizar uma função para comparar o texto em duas versões, para verificar o que foi removido/adicionado/mantido.

Uma versão eu dou upload de um arquivo html e extraio o texto puro, e a outra versão eu obtenho do meu banco de dados, e também extraio o texto puro, para comparação.

Vocês conhecem alguma função desse tipo a ser utilizada do gitHub ou qualquer outra fonte?

Já tentei utilizar a função desse site http://code.iamkate.com/php/diff-implementation/ mas eles comparam linha por linha, o que não é funcional, pois na versão 2, é possível que um parágrafo tenha sido adicionado, e se for comparar linha por linha individualmente, a partir de uma adição, todas as próximas comparações indicarão modificação, o que não é verdade.

De forma manual, a melhor ferramenta que encontrei foi https://www.diffchecker.com/ mas eles não tem uma api e nem código aberto.

Esperto ter sido claro o suficiente.

Exemplo do output que quero: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o projeto https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-diff no GitHub que se encaixou perfeitamente com minha necessidade. O exemplo é muito interessante. E o resultado ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É impressionante como tem pessoas que não gostam de ajudar a comunidade, deixei aqui a resposta com a função encontrada para resolver tal problema e pessoas negativam sem deixar explicação para melhorar o conteúdo.

Answer (score 2):

O que você está procurando se chama text diff

Tem algumas  opições:

[PHP Inline Diff](http://web.archive.org/web/20080506155528/http://software.zuavra.net/inline-diff/) (uses PEAR text-diff)

[PEAR Text_Diff](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff)

[Diff in Pure PHP](http://www.holomind.de/phpnet/diff2.src.php)

[xdiff_string_diff()](http://www.phpf1.com/manual/xdiff-string-diff.html)

Assuntos relacionados no Stackoverflow em  ingles:

[Highlight the difference between two strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php)

[Apply Diff in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414652/apply-diff-in-php)

[Need Help Optimizing php string difference function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957155/need-help-optimizing-php-string-difference-function)

> Fontes
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125248/how-to-highlight-changes-difference-in-one-text-paragraph-from-the-other

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Mas encontrei um código no gitHub que ficou perfeito.