# Como calcular porcentagem de diferença (ou similaridade) entre duas strings?

Tags: php, string

Estou usando PHP em um aplicação que estou desenvolvendo, onde possuo um editor de texto.

Nesse editor de texto, a cada alteração feita, antes de salvar, eu crio um registro com os dados originais (ou seja, como eles são antes da alteração ser concluída).

Além disso, agora me surgiu uma demanda onde eu preciso calcular a porcentagem de mudança de textos, bem como descobrir qual trecho cada usuário editou.

Eu acho que estou a meio caminho de saber cada trecho editado através dessa pergunta: [Comparar textos php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292565/comparar-textos-php)

Porém eu preciso saber: Existe alguma maneira de calcular a porcentagem de diferença (ou semelhança) entre dois textos em PHP?

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Uma duvida, vc grava esse texto ''original'' em algum lugar? Pois se grava em uma coluna em uma tabela, ao ser editado, gravaria em outra coluna, então poderia realizar a comparação entre ambos os textos.

Comment: Não. Eu utilizo o framework Laravel. Nesse, é possível criar relacionamento polimórfico. Então eu faço isso usando uma tabela chamada `registro_atividades`, onde salvo em formato `JSON` todas os dados daquela tabela. Ou seja, para cada alteração, eu crio um registro daquele texto em outra tabela.

Comment: Muito mais ou menos relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1828/101

Comment: Tenho uma função em PL/SQL que calcula a similaridade entre dois textos. Quer traduzi-la?

Comment: Manda ae bro @ReginaldoRigo

Answer (score 1):

#### Porcentagem de similaridade

No PHP existe uma função chamada [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.similar-text.php), ela serve para encontrar a similaridade entre duas strings. Segue a descrição da documentação da linguagem sobre esta função:

> similar_text — Calcula a similaridade entre duas strings

Sabendo o propósito da função, basta adicionar um terceiro parâmetro para obter a porcentagem da similaridade.

```
similar_text('Hello World!', 'Hello World!', $percentage);
echo $percentage; // Resulta 100, que é a porcentagem.
```